# How to not cancel the animate().alpha(1).setDuration(100)

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I was trying to write code that displays an `ImageView` fading and then fades out, so it comes on screen and then it disappears, now, I did try this code

```
banana.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(3000);
banana.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000);
```

Now as you can see these two lines are fading an `ImageView` called `banana` that should take about 3 seconds, and then fade out in another three second, making a total of 6 seconds of animation, but it doesn't do that, instead the second line cancels the first line making the image never to appear.

Is there is a possibility to make it appear and disappear without any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are trying to draw them at the same time. So you need a type of callback or listener that tells you the first animation is done, to proceed to the second.

```
banana.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(3000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            banana.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can also use [`withEndAction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable)) if you just care about the end state rather than the full `AnimatorListener` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`withEndAction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
banana.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(3000)
    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            banana.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000);
        }
    });
```

You can instead use a custom [TimeInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html) that will automatically reverse the animation, here's one I just knocked up:

```
import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

/**
 * Maps time into another interpolator so that the animation plays, and then reverses.
 * i.e. time maps like so:
 * [0..0.5, 0.5..1] maps to [0..1, 1..0]
 */
public final class AutoReverseInterpolator implements TimeInterpolator {

    private final TimeInterpolator inner;

    /**
     * Decorator constructor, use if you don't want a linear interpolation.
     * @param inner
     */
    public AutoReverseInterpolator(TimeInterpolator inner) {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    /**
     * Linear interpolation constructor.
     */
    public AutoReverseInterpolator() {
        this(new LinearInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        input *= 2;
        if (input > 1) {
            input = 2 - input;
        }
        return inner.getInterpolation(input);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
banana.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(6000)
      .setInterpolator(new AutoReverseInterpolatorDecorator());
```

Or for more complex chain of animations, you should look at using xml to define the animation or use an [`AnimatorSet`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

Comment: The `.withEndAction()` actually is what I was looking for, less code and able to be use repeatedly for my code. Cheers